# Why don't people utilize the Rinnegan to its fullest?

Tags: naruto

#### This question contains spoilers for anime viewers and early manga readers.

We've seen Nagato use his Rinnegan to the fullest, using the Rikudo technique (to control 6 bodies)

> As well as by fighting alone, as a reincarnated zombie.

He utilized all 6 paths of the Rinnegan.

---

> So why don't Obito and Madara? Madara only used the Preta Path, to absorb incoming ninjutsu. Obito only *tried* to use the Human Path, to try and kill Naruto.

Why don't they use any other realms? Their Rinnegan is supposedly perfect. I can't imagine they're holding back on purpose, the Rinnegan has some pretty scary abilities.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can be fairly certain Madara is just too strong without using the Rinnegan *at all*. Although Madara's strength has never been explicitly discussed, we can infer it indirectly through other plot points. Madara fought on par with the Senju Hashirama, who used to have the 9 bijuu as his "pets". Other badass characters have had a lot of trouble dealing with just one.

> It is heavily implied that the battle happened *before* Madara activated his Rinnegan. During the fourth ninja world war, Madara effortlessly mopped the floor with the five Kages. If Madara did use the Rinnegan, Kishimoto-sensei may have chosen to skip it to retain suspense over its powers.
>
> Obito has only implanted the Rinnegan (and not "earned" it, like Madara). Maybe overusing Rinnegan drains his chakra rapidly (just like overusing Sharingan does to Kakashi), and hence he chose to not use it fully. Alternately, Kishimoto-sensei wants to save it for the climax.

Nagato being able to use it could be because:

> Being from the Uzumaki clan, he naturally has a huge amount of chakra. Madara likely chose him to receive the Rinnegan for that reason. Madara's plan involved getting himself revived through Rinne Tensei. He had to pick someone who could reliably use the Outer Path without passing out.

Another key difference between the three:

> Nagato received his Rinnegan when he was a child, and must have learnt to use the full powers of Rinnegan through years of practice. Madara awakened the Rinnegan shortly before he died, and Obito has had it for only a few weeks at most.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, There is no sure way to answer this question.

> At this moment, The manga in chapter 613 and they still did not revealed enough information exposed to enough information to establish the claim that shown in any way that you and Obito can not use these Abilities, So we can only guess.
> We can assume that they did not have need to use them, Because they are (Obviously) still at advantage.

Answer (score 1):

They didnt have both Rinnegan eyes. 
Madara had the left Rinnegan and Obito had the right Rinnegan.
Thus they could not use all paths since I guess some reside on the left, some on the right and some are awakened when both eyes are used

Answer (score 0):

Madara is like Akuma from street fighter. He *loves* to fight, but he knows his power is too much for just about everyone. So, in order to enjoy his fight, Madara holds back when going against the five kage. When he does use his final susanoo to finish them, and it turns out that the five kage survived- he flat out says it is a matter of pride.

If he spams the Rinnegan, he'd be disgracing himself in his own eyes.